# Junit. Is there a way to get output formatted like rspec output?

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I usually code in ruby, and use rspec for my unit tests.

Now I have to do some work in java, so I'm using JUnit. The output from multiple test suites looks like this;

```
test:
    [junit] Running com.whatever.MapperTest
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.542 sec
    [junit] Running com.whatever.ReducerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.391 sec
    [junit] Running com.whatever.DenormalizerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.046 sec
    [junit] Running com.whatever.EventTest
    [junit] Tests run: 31, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.081 sec

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

That's quite dense text, and makes it a bit difficult to see failures and errors.

With RSpec, I get output like this;

```
............F........F........E.......
```

Where '.' represents a passing test, 'F' is a failure and 'E' is an error. Below this output is detail of all the failures/errors.

I find that format a lot easier to look at - failures and errors leap out in a way that they don't when looking at the counts of run/fails/errors in the normal summary output from JUnit.

I have been through a couple of options in the junit task of the build.xml file, including;

```
<formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
```

and

```
<junit printsummary="true">
```

Using formatter="plain" fills the screen with too much redundant information. I don't need to see every single pass listed out as a line of text - just a single dot is ideal.

Does anyone know if a custom formatter has been written that produces something similar to the format I want?

Whatever tool I use needs to work on the command line, so fancy GUI tools aren't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own formatter to solve the problem.

Here are some good instructions to get you started:
http://shaman-sir.wikidot.com/one-liner-output-formatter

Basically, you'll want to change addError to keep a record of tests with errors also.  Then change endTest() to output a . instead of all the information there unless the test is in the failure or error Set.

The API for ANT is included with the binary distribution of it.  Remember to update the junit formatter classname with the newly created formatter.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm making some progress with my formatter, but I've hit a snag. I can only hook into the start and end of individual test suites (i.e. single java classes containing a set of tests). So, I'm spitting out a line of dots per suite of tests. Is there any way to get at the start and end of the *whole* set of test suites, so I can collect the dots for all the tests in all the suites and output them as one block?

Comment: Yea, it doesn't look like there is a straight forward solution to that.  It seems like it might be based on the runner that you're using.  You could try grouping your tests into a suite and then running that (to see if endTest() fires after the suite).  You might be able to use a RunListener.  It has a function testRunFinished(), which seems like it may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using a RunListener